# How to send SMS in php API without json response?

Tags: php, json, api, sms

I am using following code to send SMS in php API.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://wpsms.whitepearldemo.biz....?user=".$user."&password=".$password."&msisdn=".$msisdn."&sid=".$sid."&msg=".$msg."&fl=".$fl."&gwid=".$gwid);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Including this response, I also have another response. So it looks like

```
{
//SMS default response
{"ErrorCode":"000","ErrorMessage":"Success","JobId":"381a80-157cc2142bfa","MessageData":[{"MobileNumber":"919898xxxxxx ","MessageParts":[{"MessageId": "919898xxxxxx -67e3765cdf034f438","MessagePartId":1,"MessageText":"test message"}]}]}
}{
//another response
...
}
```

When this api called, everything worked properly but app this error -

> "onFailer: JSON document was not fully consumed."

.

If I comment SMS code temporarily, no error occurs.
Can we avoid the response of SMS?
Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Is this android? Or else, I think your question is unclear. Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: This SMS code is used in PHP API.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my question...Use following code to send SMS without JSON response.

```
$data = array(
    'user' => $user,
    'password' => $password,
    'msisdn' => $msisdn,
    'sid' => $sid,                          
    'gwid' => $gwid,
    'fl' => $fl,
    'msg' => 'Hi'
        );

    $curl = curl_init('http://wpsms.whitepearldemo......?format=xml');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

Thanks & regards.